# Flights within Australia allowed on a subclass 400 visa? Is there a more suitable visa for me?

Tags: visas, australia

I am currently in Australia on a subclass 651 visa. I am planning to leave for two weeks to go to NZ and apply for a subclass 400 visa so I can do work for my company in the UK. I want to do some travel while I am doing work in Australia - see Sydney, Melbourne, Uluru etc.

One of the provisos on the visa - 
"If you are granted a single entry visa, you will only be allowed to enter Australia once. If so, you will need to apply for a new visa if you want to return to Australia after you leave."

This implies I would be safe traveling within Australia on this visa then correct, since I wouldn't be re-entering...or would I potentially have a lot of headaches here ?

Also, is this even the right visa? I am working for my company in the UK, and will be paid in the UK only. I do not satisfy this requirement :

"You need to be in Australia to do the work or activity"

...I don't NEED to be.  I am here visiting an ill friend and want to continue to work remotely for my UK company....there doesn't seem to be ANY visa for which I am suitable though, except for POSSIBLY a 457 which has a three month lead time (and my friend will have passed away by then).

Is there a better visa to get here ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Most domestic flights within Australia do not require you to go through passport control and do not require any identification. Taking these flights is no different from driving.

However, a small number of internal flights are actually one leg of a longer international flight. These flights are outside customs and immigration control and you need to pass through immigration twice. These should be clearly identified when you buy the ticket, but be sure to check. The clue will be they arrive and depart at international terminals.

For your visa question, it is hard to answer but remember that there is no guarantee of receiving a visa even if it appears you would qualify for one. I would suggest that you stay in Australia until you are finished with your friend rather than leave and hope you can come back.